# ZEND framework2 new module blank page

Tags: php, zend-framework2

i'm a beginner with zend framework2,
i followed two tutorial on how to build module, followed instruction step by step, but when finished i have a blank page on my browser!!
one of my tutorials is:Zend Framework 2.0 by Example(creating user module)
what should that according to??

Comment: Did you check your http server's (apache/nginx) error and access logs?

Comment: provide your apache error log as @foozy mentioned; How did you created your skeleton application?

Comment: @foozy
Here is apache error for this issue:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend\\ModuleManager\\Exception\\RuntimeException' with message 'Module (Users) could not be initialized.' 
i will add all files of module in answers

Comment: You should configure your php to show errors in dev environment. Look at the directives ```error_reporting``` and ```display_errors``` in you php.ini.

Comment: Does the default module work well? I think it needs more information for one to answer. put your module file structure, application.config.php, module.config.php and your main controller and view files into your question.

Answer (score 0):

> 'Module (Users) could not be initialized.'

As you mentioned in your comment it could be the problem of missing module(Users) name in application.config.php which is located under config folder.

```
return array (
 'modules' => array(
    'Application', 'Users' //<== mentioned your module name here
  ),
  ....
);
```

--SJ

Comment: please update your answers to your question and then delete your answers! if someone face the same problem of yours they may get confused